# Ensure that a function runs every second (if the time it takes to complete that function varies)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having is that the function takes a varying amount of time to complete. Sometimes it's less than 1 second and sometimes it's more. On average, it takes under 1 second to run, but in the beginning, it takes longer.

Thus, is there a way to somehow ensure that the function runs once per second by making sure it doesn't run more than once per second? That way this wouldn't delay the initial output further, but rather restrict the later output to a certain time interval.

Comment: Can you clarify what behavior you want? If the fn can take >1s to run, do you expect a) every 1s, the function will be invoked again even if it's still running b) every 1s, the function will be invoked if it's not still running from the previous time c) something else?

Comment: It sounds like what OP wants is a tick function similar to the kind used to control framerates in games, but they are unclear about what behavior they expect if an update takes longer than the tick interval allows. In games this just causes the framerate to drop and the game to lag, but OP could want something different, so we need to know that before we write a solution.

Comment: The function is being repeated using a loop, sorry forgot to clarify. When the function is finished, it is repeated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
from time import sleep, time

def foo():
  start = time()

  # your code

  time_elapsed = time() - start
  sleep(max(1 - time_elapsed, 0))
```

Let's say your function took 0.7s, then the function sleeps for 1 - 0.7 = 0.3s

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: That's really great!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is start a threading operation that runs exactly at one second interval. So after each one second, your function runs. For an example I'm showing you a recurrent function that calls itself on 1 second interval to run a function.

```
import threading

def start_automate():
    global AUTOMATE
    AUTOMATE = threading.Timer(1, start_automate)
    AUTOMATE.start()
    #your_task_here
```

In order to stop it:

```
AUTOMATE.cancel()
```

You can also define a decorator for this process like:

```
def automate_1sec(fn):
    def wrapper():
        global auto
        auto = threading.Timer(1, wrapper)
        auto.start()
        fn()
    return wrapper

@automate_1sec
def test():
    print('testing in 1 sec')
```